# Accessing Android Context in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-context

I've seen some old solutions to getting the Android Context using Xamarin.Forms. These older solution suggest the use of `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` but due to the ever changing Xamarin.Forms platform this no longer works.

In my example I have used the `DependencyService.Get<Interface>()` from my Shared Code project to use a platform specific implementation of the `Interface` class.

The use of Android Context is needed a ton when using platform specific functionality using Xamarin.Andriod.

So how do we get the global information interface for an Android Context?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. Go to the class you created in your App.Droid project part of your solution.
2. Make sure you have `using Android.Content;` included at the top.
3. Create a variable to hold the Context and initialize it with `Android.App.Application.Context`.

That's it!

```
using Android.Content;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DroidClass))]
namespace App.Droid
{
   public class DroidClass : Interface
   {
     Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

     public DroidClass()
     {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Grabbed Context!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
         }  
      }
   }
```

Comment: To also ensure that a memory leak doesn't happen, I always like to put in a Weak Reference whenever I'm using the context.  Remember to check for Null if it's been garbage collected.

WeakReference<Context> context = new WeakReference<Context>(Application.Context);